# prerex package changes toc color

Tags: table-of-contents, color

I use the prerex package to draw a simple prerequisite diagram. It works well, but changes the table of contents color to red, what looks ugly. I tried to change it back with

```
{\color{black}\tableofcontents}
```

but it remains red.

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{prerex}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Prerequisites}
    \begin{chart}
      \text 35,40:{Főcsoport}
    \end{chart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, don't add “SOLVED” tags on your question titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colour is caused by the `hyperref` package which is loaded by `prerex` with the following options: `urlcolor=black,colorlinks,raiselinks`. This causes internal links to be coloured the default red colour.

What to do depends on what you want.

1. You can disable hyperlinks all together:

   ```
   \hypersetup{draft}
   ```
2. You can set the colour of hyperlinks to black and put coloured boxes around them:

   ```
   \hypersetup{colorlinks=false}
   ```
3. You can set the colour of hyperlinks to black and remove the boxes around them:

   ```
   \hypersetup{colorlinks=false,pdfborder=0 0 0}
   ```
4. See the `hyperref` documentation for further options.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{prerex}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
% Choose one of the following
%\hypersetup{draft}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=false,
  pdfborder=0 0 0}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Prerequisites}
    \begin{chart}
      \text 35,40:{Főcsoport}
    \end{chart}
\end{document}
```